# Enclosing <img> with <p>

Tags: php, html, css

On my website I have some images that are stored in the same SQL-cell as the rest of the content. When I load the page containing the images and PHP echoes the 'article'-cell, the images are automatically enclosed in paragraph-tags, which is not what I want. Is there any way to prevent this? I'm not exactly sure wether it's a browser-side or a server-side issue, but it appears in botch Chrome and FF.

SQL-cell 'article':

```
<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

PHP Code:

```
if ($pageType == 'article') {
            if($pageExists==1) {
                try {
                    $db = new PDO('pdoinfo');
                } catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}

                $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=$pageName");
                $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                echo ('<div class="article"><h3>');
                echo $result[0]->title;
                echo('</h3><p>');
                echo $result[0]->article;
                echo('<span class="article-data">Geplaatst op <span class="article-date">');
                echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result[0]->postdate));
                echo ('</span> door <span class="article-author">');
                echo $result[0]->author;
                echo ('</span><span class="article-broadcast"><span class="st_twitter_hcount" displayText="Tweet"></span><span class="st_facebook_hcount" displayText="Facebook"></span>');
                echo ('</span></span></div>');
            }
            else {
                include('pages/404.php');
            }
        }
```

Output HTML:

```
[...]<p><img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/297522main_image_1244_946-710.jpg"><p>Lorem ipsum</p>[...]
```

I just code everything myself, so no CMS involved.
When I enclose the image with p-tags myself, a redundant empty p-tag get's inserted before the paragraph.

Comment: There could be 20 reasons. What CMS are you using? Can you show us the output code or a link to your site? Or even better the PHP that's generating the output?

Comment: There's no way for us to answer without more details about the system.  Code samples of where the content is rendered?  What the relevant PHP code looks like?  Are you storing the html-to-render in the database?  It could be doing the `<p>` tag enclosing before saving it to the database.

Comment: If p tags are appearing in HTML source, its server side issue. Most likely, the CMS (WYSIWYG editor) adds the p tag when the content is created. Use HTML editor.

Comment: As I said, I'm not using a CMS

Comment: Gosh, how could I overlook that! Thank you ;) *Feels stupid*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an opening `<p>` on this line `echo('</h3><p>');` that never closes so i suspect your seeing that.

There is also no need for all thos echos's

```
echo '
<div class="article">
    <h3>'.$result[0]->title.'</h3>
    '.$result[0]->article.'
    <span class="article-data">
        Geplaatst op <span class="article-date">'.date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result[0]->postdate)).'</span> door 
        <span class="article-author">'.$result[0]->author.'</span>
        <span class="article-broadcast">
            <span class="st_twitter_hcount" displayText="Tweet"></span>
            <span class="st_facebook_hcount" displayText="Facebook"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>';
```

Comment: Most browsers automatically generate the closing tag. But we should always close the tags.

Comment: How does it keep it readable when half the screen is filled with the word `echo`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many popular html editor (e.g. CKEditor) adds `<p>` around `<img>` tag by default. Are you generating this content using a html editor?

Comment: No, as you can see I'm echoing the code from SQL, so that cant be the case

Comment: It does?  That doesn't even make sense since `<img>` is a block-level element and `<p>` tags are not allowed to contain block-level elements.

Comment: @nzifnab: `<img>` is not a block element; it's actually an inline-block element, and `<p>` are allowed to contain inline-block elements.